# How to separate and modify the content of a string in php?

Tags: php, date, time

I read a csv file like this one :

```
  391;WETSUITS;07/07/2020 12:47:36;0021000001463;
  392;WETSUITS;07/07/2020 12:47:49;0021000007845;
             ....
```

I retrieve the one date with this format :

```
echo $data[2] = 07/07/2020 12:47:36
```

I would like to have two variables :

```
$date = 07-07-2020 or 2020-07-07
$time = 1247
```

I tried with str_replace for the first part but I get "Notice: Undefined offset: 2" as an error message, how can I change this?

```
 <?php

$csv = 'C:/wamp64/www/BI/BI1_20200707_1520_28044.csv';


if (($handle = fopen("$csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 9000000, ";")) !== FALSE){

            // echo $data[2]; //07/07/2020 12:47:36

        $new = str_replace('/', '_', $data[2]);
        echo $date = substr($new,0,20)."\n";;
 
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Not reaaly clear for what line you get the notice. If `echo $data[2]` shows correct data, then `str_replace` should work too.

Comment: You asked this question earlier and it was closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916). Your title would indicate this is a still a dupe but the error you mention is completely different. Which problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: I have a error at the line "$new = str_replace('/', '_', $data[2]);" @u_mulder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This notice may come because of an empty line at the end of file.
So, just check if the `$data` array is empty.

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 9000000, ";")) !== false) {
        // empty line will be transformed to [null]
        if (empty(array_filter($data))) {
            continue;
        }

    // other operations
}
```

Advice: Better is to use DateTime for operations with dates. Date format reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date

```
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $data[2]);
if ($date === false) {
    // handle date parse error
}

$date1 = $date->format('Y-m-d'); // 2020-07-07
$date2 = $date->format('Hi'); // 1247
```

Comment: This doesn't address the error message in their question

Comment: First line does

Comment: I tried your code and I got a run-time error: "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on boolean" @DmitrySolovov

Comment: You have to do something with date parsing errors (in an if-block with a comment `// handle date parse error`). Place `continue` or `break`, may be log the error.

Comment: If I put a break or a continue in the if instead of "// handle date parse error" I don't get anything displayed @Dmitry Solovov

Comment: How can I display the two variables $date1 and $date2? @DmitrySolovov

Comment: They are string variables, so `echo $date1; echo $date2;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217416/discussion-between-eric27-and-dmitry-solovov).